# How do I extract URLs within HTML from a Google Sheets cell?

Tags: html, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of cells that each include raw HTML. I want to extract all the URLs from each cell (some cells contain multiple URLs).

So from a cell that has:

```
<p>This is <a href="https://www.test.com">only</a> a test! Do not <a href="https://www.afraid.com">be</a> afraid!</p>
```

I want it to just say `https://www.test.com` and `https://www.afraid.com` in separate adjacent cells in the same row.

I think I can use REGEXEXTRACT, but I'm a huge novice when it comes Regex, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
                          REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2:A, """>", 0),
                          "^?https?:\/\/(.+[com|org|net]?)"),"")), " where Col1 is not null"))))
```

[image]